# Update has_many association from array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models connected with has_many through association.
`Book` can have many authors and `Author` many books.

In `AuthorsController` in `update` action from API I get author's id and an array of books ids `Parameters: {"books"=>"3,4,5", "id"=>"1"}` and I need to update author's books with them.
What is the best way to achieve that?

I tried `author.books << Book.where(id: params[:books])` but the problem here is that if a book is already in author's books it will be duplicated.

Comment: The simplest way to solve your problem is to change your params from `books` to `book_ids` and then ActiveRecord will take care of the rest. See [ActiveRecord Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and `collection_singular_ids=ids`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
author.books << Book.where(id: params[:books])
```

Performs unnecessary database queries.

You may need to remove the books that are already in the database

```
books_array = params[:books].split(',') - author.books.pluck(:id)
books_array.each do |a|
  author.author_books.build(book_id: a)
end

# I assumed author_books is the join table
```

Answer (score 14):

The most efficient way is to use: has_many Association Reference.
vide: [Rails 4 Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

```
4.3.1 Methods Added by has_many
```

When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class automatically gains 16 methods related to the association:

```
collection(force_reload = false)
collection<<(object, ...)
collection.delete(object, ...)
collection.destroy(object, ...)
collection=(objects)
collection_singular_ids
**collection_singular_ids=(ids)**
collection.clear
collection.empty?
collection.size
collection.find(...)
collection.where(...)
collection.exists?(...)
collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)
collection.create(attributes = {})
collection.create!(attributes = {})
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: **CAREFUL!!** Removing ids with `order_ids=(ids)` will remove the JOIN record and **NOT** call any callbacks. For that you'll need to use `before_remove` on the `has_many` association.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be too late, but you could also try

```
author.book_ids.push(params[:books]).flatten.uniq!
```

it'd be a little shorter and a single request.

Answer (score -1):

If param[:books] is a string of numbers, you can convert it to an array with

```
"3,4,5".split(',').map {|x| x.to_i}
-> [3, 4, 5]
```

Then with [Rails Collection methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-singular-ids), `author.book_ids` should return an array that can be subtracted.  So in all the feature would resemble:

```
author.books << Book.where(id: params[:books].split(',').map {|x| x.to_i} - author.book_ids)
```